# a way to make this array/matrix multiplication faster? in R

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I cannot think of a way to make this code faster.  Is there an apply function that would run faster?  Now, I am using a for each loop to run this loop in parallel, and it still takes a VERY long time.

```
ndraws=20000
nhousehold=18831
m=12


    elasticitydraws = array(0,c(m,ndraws,nhousehold))
    MAPelasticity = matrix(0,nhousehold,m)
    medianpricemat = matrix(rnorm(12,15,1),12,1)                                 


# dim(out$betadraw) = 18831, 12, 20000
# dim(medianpricemat) = 12, 1

    library(foreach)
    library(doMC)
    registerDoMC(10)

    elasticitylist = foreach(i=1:nhousehold) %dopar% {

            pricedraws = out$betadraw[i,12,] 
            elasticitydraws[,,i]= probarray[,,i] %*% diag(pricedraws)
            elasticitydraws[,,i] = elasticitydraws[,,i] * as.vector(medianpricemat)
            MAPelasticity[i,] = apply(elasticitydraws[,,i],1,mean)

    }
```

Comment: A couple minor things: create `vecmp<-as.vector(medianpricemat)` outside the loops to avoid recalculating;  and I suspect your `apply(elasticitydraws[,,i],1,mean)` is just `rowMeans()`

Comment: Thanks Carl, I will fix this.  I think the real slow steps are the second and third line calculations (in the loop.)  Is there a way to do this using apply or a single type of reshaping to make it just linear alg rather than looping?

Comment: library(Matrix) is your friend. Your problem is the  matrix multiplication. diag(pricedraws ) constructs a 20000 * 20000 dense matrix in each iteration. Just use a sparse diagonal matrix instead the code should run around 20000 times faster. The foreach loop is likely to worsen your problem as you will run out of memory.

Comment: I don't know about `foreach` specifically, but for some frameworks, having larger chunks of work per process is more efficient.  You might try calling 'foreach(i=seq.int(celiing(nhousehold/10)))` and in each dopar block, calling 'for(i in 10*i + 1:10){...}'.   This involves a bit of book keeping, though since `nhousehold` is not a multiple of 10, and it may or may not be more efficient depending on how foreach manages the parallel computations.  Just something to try...

Comment: The sparse matrix thing actually makes the loop very fast!! If Klash answers I will best it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck in the code is the creation a large dense diagonal matrix and matrix multiplication with this. It is better using a sparse matrix and the `Matrix` package. This saves memory and computational time. I also included Carl's comments and created a few vectors outside the loop.

```
library(Matrix)

medianpricemat <-  as.vector(medianpricemat)
D1 <- Diagonal(x=pricedraws)

elasticitylist = foreach(i=1:nhousehold) %dopar% {
    pricedraws = out$betadraw[i,12,] 
    tmp = probarray[,,i] %*% D1
    elasticitydraws[,,i] = as.matrix(tmp) * medianpricemat
    MAPelasticity[i,] = rowMeans(elasticitydraws[,,i])
}
```

A less obvious hack is to avoid creation of the diagonal matrix and the
matrix multiplication:

```
D2 <- rep(pricedraws, each=m)

elasticitylist = foreach(i=1:nhousehold) %dopar% {
    pricedraws = out$betadraw[i,12,] 
    tmp = probarray[,,i] * D2  # element wise multiplication 
    elasticitydraws[,,i] = as.matrix(tmp) * medianpricemat
    MAPelasticity[i,] = rowMeans(elasticitydraws[,,i]) 
}
```